# Bullets on the help page on bounties are partially cut off in Firefox and IE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the [help page on bounties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), the left half of the bullet points are cut off for me in Firefox:

[image]

[IE 10 in Windows 7 also has a very slight cutoff.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzcAd.png)

[This isn't a problem on most sites like M.SO, though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdCyc.png); there's no white area thingy because the background's the same color.

[It works fine in Chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3cgI.png)

Comment: Repro'd here. Firefox 22.0, Windows 7.

Comment: Same as @RavenDreamer.

Comment: CSS error due to discrepancies between layout engines. Should be a simple fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is fixed on dev, it will be on live after the next prod build.